# Flatten a map after Collectors.groupingBy in java

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have list of students.
I want to return list of objects StudentResponse classes that has the course and the list of students for the course.
So I can write which gives me a map

```
Map<String, List<Student>> studentsMap = students.stream().
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCourse,
                    Collectors.mapping(s -> s, Collectors.toList()
             )));
```

Now I have to iterate through the map again to create a list of objects of  `StudentResponse` class which has the Course and List:

```
class StudentResponse {
     String course;
     Student student;

     // getter and setter
}
```

Is there a way to combine these two iterations?

Comment: Or like this `Map<String,StudentResponse> map = new HashMap<>();
        students.forEach(student -> {
            List<Student> value = new ArrayList<>();
            value.add(student);
            map.merge(student.getCourse(), new StudentResponse(student.getCourse(), value),
                    (sr1, sr2) -> {
                        sr1.getStudentList().addAll(sr2.getStudentList());
                        return sr1;
                    });
        });` then use `map.values();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you've asked, but here's a compact way to accomplish what you want, just for completeness:

```
Map<String, StudentResponse> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
students.forEach(s -> map.computeIfAbsent(
        s.getCourse(), 
        k -> new StudentResponse(s.getCourse()))
    .getStudents().add(s));
```

This assumes `StudentResponse` has a constructor that accepts the course as an argument and a getter for the student list, and that this list is mutable (i.e. `ArrayList`) so that we can add the current student to it.

While the above approach works, it clearly violates a fundamental OO principle, which is encapsulation. If you are OK with that, then you're done. If you want to honor encapsulation, then you could add a method to `StudentResponse` to add a `Student` instance:

```
public void addStudent(Student s) {
    students.add(s);
}
```

Then, the solution would become:

```
Map<String, StudentResponse> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
students.forEach(s -> map.computeIfAbsent(
        s.getCourse(), 
        k -> new StudentResponse(s.getCourse()))
    .addStudent(s));
```

This solution is clearly better than the previous one and would avoid a rejection from a serious code reviewer.

Both solutions rely on `Map.computeIfAbsent`, which either returns a `StudentResponse` for the provided course (if there exists an entry for that course in the map), or creates and returns a `StudentResponse` instance built with the course as an argument. Then, the student is being added to the internal list of students of the returned `StudentResponse`.

Finally, your `StudentResponse` instances are in the map values:

```
Collection<StudentResponse> result = map.values();
```

If you need a `List` instead of a `Collection`:

```
List<StudentResponse> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Note: I'm using `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` to preserve insertion-order, i.e. the order of the students in the original list. If you don't have such requirement, just use `HashMap`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably way overkill but it was a fun exercise :) You could implement your own Collector:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StudentResponseCollector implements Collector<Student, Map<String, List<Student>>, List<StudentResponse>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, List<Student>>> supplier() {
        return () -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, List<Student>>, Student> accumulator() {
        return (store, student) -> store.merge(student.getCourse(),
                new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(student)), combineLists());
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, List<Student>>> combiner() {
        return (x, y) -> {
            x.forEach((k, v) -> y.merge(k, v, combineLists()));

            return y;
        };
    }

    private <T> BiFunction<List<T>, List<T>, List<T>> combineLists() {
        return (students, students2) -> {
            students2.addAll(students);
            return students2;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, List<Student>>, List<StudentResponse>> finisher() {
        return (store) -> store
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(course -> new StudentResponse(course, store.get(course)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

Given Student and StudentResponse:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(String name, String course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + course;
    }
}

public class StudentResponse {
    private String course;
    private List<Student> studentList;

    public StudentResponse(String course, List<Student> studentList) {
        this.course = course;
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return course + ", " + studentList.toString();
    }
}
```

Your code where you collect your StudentResponses can now be very short and elegant ;)

```
public class StudentResponseCollectorTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Student student1 = new Student("Student1", "foo");
        Student student2 = new Student("Student2", "foo");
        Student student3 = new Student("Student3", "bar");

        List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(student1, student2, student3);

        List<StudentResponse> studentResponseList = studentList
                .stream()
                .collect(new StudentResponseCollector());

        assertEquals(2, studentResponseList.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your downstream collector (`mapping`) is redundant and hence you can simplify your code by using the `groupingBy` overload without a downstream collector.

Given a `List<T>` as the source, after using the `groupingBy` overload taking a classifier alone the result map is `Map<K, List<T>>` so the mapping operation can be avoided.

As for your question, you can use `collectingAndThen`:

```
students.stream()
        .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Student::getCourse), 
                   m -> m.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(a -> new StudentResponse(a.getKey(), a.getValue()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

`collectingAndThen` basically:

> Adapts a Collector to perform an additional finishing transformation.

Comment: `collectingAndThen()` can be cleaner when you want to pass the result to another function. There's no point in using it for chained methods, IMO.

Comment: @shmosel subjective matter so I prefer not to give my view on that.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the entry set and map each entry to a `StudentResponse`:

```
List<StudentResponse> responses = studentsMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new StudentResponse(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a very concise manner using the [jOOλ](https://github.com/jooq/jool) library and its [`Seq.grouped`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#grouped-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) method:

```
List<StudentResponse> responses = Seq.seq(students)
        .grouped(Student::getCourse, Collectors.toList())
        .map(Tuple.function(StudentResponse::new))
        .toList();
```

It assumes `StudentResponse` has a constructor `StudentResponse(String course, List<Student> students)`, and forwards to this constructor using the following [`Tuple.function`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple.html#function-java.util.function.BiFunction-) overload.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548602/flatten-a-map-after-collectors-groupingby-in-java/53548626#53548626) as well as [shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548602/flatten-a-map-after-collectors-groupingby-in-java/53548643#53548643), you'll eventually need to invoke `studentsMap.entrySet()` to map each `Entry<String, List<String>>` in the resulting map to `StudentResponse` objects.

Another approach you could take is the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) way; i.e.

```
Collection<StudentResponse> result = students.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Student::getCourse,
                        v -> new StudentResponse(v.getCourse(),
                                new ArrayList<>(singletonList(v))),
                        StudentResponse::merge)).values();
```

This essentially groups the `Student` object by their course (`Student::getCourse`) as with the `groupingBy` collector; then in the `valueMapper` function maps from `Student` to a `StudentResponse` and finally in the `merge` function utilises `StudentResponse::merge` in the case of a key collision.

The above has a dependency on the `StudentResponse` class having at least the following fields, constructor and methods:

```
class StudentResponse {
    StudentResponse(String course, List<Student> students) {
        this.course = course;
        this.students = students;
    }

    private List<Student> getStudents() { return students; }

    StudentResponse merge(StudentResponse another){
        this.students.addAll(another.getStudents());
        // maybe some addition merging logic in the future ...
        return this;
    }

    private String course;
    private List<Student> students;
}
```